# Wampserver not checking root subfolders //Magento site

Tags: magento, wamp, wampserver, vhosts

**Edit:** looks like it was the port that was the fault. changed port 3333 to 80 and it worked like a charm.

Heyo, I just started using Wamp with no experience to set up a local development environment and have some trouble with loading pages except the one in root directory.

Here's what I get:

[Failed loading attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTX9e.png)

If I try to navigate through the links on the site I get Page not found.

I've set up the **httpd.vhosts.conf** file as such:

```css
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:3333>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#


<VirtualHost *:3333>
    ServerName server1.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/server1.dev/htdocs"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/server1.dev/htdocs/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:3333>
    ServerName server2.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/server2.dev/htdocs"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/server2.dev/htdocs/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I've got two servers and server1 is working perfectly fine while server2 does not, both have subfolders which contain css and more pages. **Server2** is a **magento** site with large database while server1 is a normal site with no database.

I've set up the core_config_data like:

[core_config_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXvR8.png)

I don't know if I should add the port in but it didn't change anything without it. It also doesn't add the port when looking for the files or when I click through the links on the startpage.

**Expected:**
http://server2.dev:3333/media/css/style.css

**Get:**
http://server2.dev/media/css/style.css

My local.xml:

```css
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[*removed*]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[*removed*]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[server2.dev:3333]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[*removed*]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[*removed*]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[*removed*]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Did you also amend the HOSTS file?

Comment: Yes, I've added both servers to the hosts file.

Comment: Any reason why you are using a non standard port number for apache

Comment: I used a different port because I had a problem where I got redirected to that port even if I didn't set it up to direct me there in the Hosts file. Input: server2.dev. Expected: server2.dev:80. Got: server2.dev:3333. well, it's not a big problem, I'll make another question if I can't figure it out by myself :) @RiggsFolly